# Solving recurrence relation ,which formula to apply

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, substitution, recursive-algorithms

I analyzed the code given, and found the that the code runs in this order:

T(n) =\begin{cases}
4T(\frac{n}{4})+clgn ,  & \text{otherwise} \\[2ex]
d, & \text{if n ≤ 1}
\end{cases}

I want to solve it using substantiation method, I started like this:

T(n/4) = 4T(n/4^2)+clgn/4

T(n) = 4T[4T(n/4^2)+clgn/4]+clgn    **#Here I substitute in the T(n/4) in T(n)**

T(n) = 4^2T(n/4^2)+clgn +clgn

....

T(n) = 4^kT(n/4^k)+kclgn  **#General function**

Then **kclgn** => is O(lgn) ,but what is 4^kT(n/4^k) , how I can find it out?

I'm doing it right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Comment: In the exams is not permitted to use Master theorem,the point here is to use substitution or recurrence tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity assume that $n$ is a power of 4, ie $n=4^k$.
Then:

$T(n)=4T(\frac{n}{4})+c\log(n)=4(4T(\frac{n}{16})+c\log(\frac{n}{4}))+c\log(n)=16T(\frac{n}{16})+4c\log(\frac{n}{4})+c\log(n)=4^kT(1)+c(4^{k-1}\log(\frac{n}{4^{k-1}})+...+4\log(\frac{n}{4})+\log(n))$

Now use $\log_{10}(x)=\frac{\log_{4}(x)}{\log_{4}(10)}$, and $n=4^{k}$.

$T(n)=4^kT(1)+\frac{c}{\log_{4}(10)}(4^{k-1}\log_{4}(\frac{4^k}{4^{k-1}})+...+4\log_{4}(4^{k}/4)+\log_4(4^k))$
$=4^kT(1)+\frac{c}{\log_{4}(10)}(4^{k-1}+(2)4^{k-2}+...+(k-1)4+(k)4^{0})$
$=4^{k}T(1)+\frac{c}{\log_{4}(10)}(\sum_{i=1}^{k}i4^{k-i})$
$=4^{k}T(1)+\frac{c}{9\log_{4}(10)}(-3k+4^{k+1}-4)$

Finally $k=log_{4}(n)$, which means that $T(n)=\Theta(4^{k+1})=\Theta(n)$

(I believe I spot an error in your workings, namely you forgot a factor of 4 when expanding brackets).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply :) I have a question when you multiply 4 on clog(n/4) shouldn't be clogn?

Comment: No, in general $4\log(n)=\log(n^4)$, and not $\log(4n)$, so $4 \times clog(\frac{n}{4})=4c\log(\frac{n}{4})$ (and not $c\log(4n)$)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!